Sending transaction that expiry early instead of 150 blocks validity
How do I send transaction which only valid for next X blocks, instead of default 150 blocks / ~ 1 minute (https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions#recent-blockhash).
I need the transaction to fail fast, I need X to be in small number, i.e : 10-20 blocks instead of full 150 blocks.
const { lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash({ commitment: "confirmed" });
    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: payer,
        recentBlockhash: blockhash,
        instructions,
    }).compileToV0Message(); // how do i get the value here which only valid for next X blocks ?
    
    const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
    transaction.sign([payerKey]);
    const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction);
    
    // wait 1 minute
    await connection.confirmTransaction(
        {
          blockhash: blockhash,
          lastValidBlockHeight: lastValidBlockHeight,
          signature: signature,
        },
        "confirmed"
      );


This is a bit of a hack, but rather than using getLatestBlockhash, you can fetch the recent blockhashes sysvar account and use any one of the old values: https://explorer.solana.com/address/SysvarRecentB1ockHashes11111111111111111111
If you fetch the account with jsonParsed encoding, you can see all the blockhashes, so you can just take an old one:
$ curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
                               {
                                 "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                                 "id": 1,
                                 "method": "getAccountInfo",
                                 "params": [
                                   "SysvarRecentB1ockHashes11111111111111111111",
                                   {
                                     "encoding": "jsonParsed"
                                   }
                                 ]
                               }
                             ' | jq
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "context": {
      "apiVersion": "1.18.14",
      "slot": 303325292
    },
    "value": {
      "data": {
        "parsed": {
          "info": [
            {
              "blockhash": "6XziWoKgEWgcgqHoAxVGXUzsw7t7D1koD6qDQrxBW6tV",
              "feeCalculator": {
                "lamportsPerSignature": "5000"
              }
            },
            {
              "blockhash": "G5NY5fBdcXXezZoJ5cvHzHNtq4DLBpBRr2Lo7cjip8ox",
              "feeCalculator": {
                "lamportsPerSignature": "5000"
              }
            },
// and so on and so on


Thanks Jon, and how do I calculate validity of these hashes? Like how do I know these hashes valid for next X blocks? And are these blocks are finalized blocks?

I guess it could calculate them if there is blockheight of every hashes I got. But these are just hashes?

All of the hashes are valid block hashes on the fork that you query. As for their finality, it depends on the bank that you query using the commitment parameter in the RPC call -- if you ask for finalized, then the top hash will be finalized. If you ask for confirmed, and not yet finalized, then the top hash will only be confirmed. The hashes are given in reverse block height order, so you can choose one X from the end if you only want it to be valid for X blocks.

You could possibly try sending an older blockhash. It still has to be within the last 150, but if you, for example, send a blockhash that was 100 slots ago, then it will be valid for only 50 blocks.

I they used a newer one, lets say for example one that is 10 blocks old, then the transaction would be valid for the next 140 blocks, that is not what they wanted. It needs to become invalid soon, so you need to use an older blockhash.

ah you're right! Good point.
